# Separate ip6tables xt_recent

Tags: iptables, ip6tables

Is is possible to create separate iptables and ip6tables xt_recent?
Like how hashlimit is separated to ipt_hashlimit and ip6t_hashlimit.

So maybe like xt_recent and x6t_recent.

Comment: What do you mean? Why do you want separate modules?

Comment: Looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: This is what I hate about Internet forums.
When asking how everybody seems to want to know why.
It's like asking how to change a light bulb and everybody wants to know why you want to change the light bulb.  Presumably so they can give other solutions like go buy a new lamp if you need more light.
Well if I'm asking how to change a light bulb then I've already detirmined that changing the light bulb is what I want to do.

No it is not an XY problem.  Have already determined what I want to do and the solution that I desire.  The questing is if that is possible.